# How to increase Android Opencv camera FPS?

Tags: java, opencv, android, javacameraview

I am developing an Android application and I'm processing frames using Opencv in real time.

The image processing is heavy as I'm detecting the largest contour, rotating and cropping it and apply some sort of segmentation on the cropped `Mat` object.

The problem is that **FPS** start with a value of 3 and drops to 1.

I'm not doing some heavy operations like `matToBitmap` and I'm not making native calls yet.

It's my first big project and I don't have much experience in Opencv. What can I do to increase my FPS?

Here is my code:

```
  long e1 = Core.getTickCount();

    Mat mGray = new Mat();

    MatOfDouble mu = new MatOfDouble();

    MatOfDouble stddev = new MatOfDouble();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(origMat, origMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(origMat, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Core.meanStdDev(mGray, mu, stddev);

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGray, mGray, new Size(5, 5), 5);

    Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mGray, (mu.get(0, 0)[0]) * 0.66, (mu.get(0, 0)[0]) * 1.33, 3, false);

    Mat kernell = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(9, 9));

    Imgproc.morphologyEx(mGray, mGray, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernell);

    Imgproc.dilate(mGray, mGray, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(3, 3)));

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

    Imgproc.findContours(mGray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    double largest_area = 0;

    Rect rect = new Rect();
    int largest_idx = 0;

    for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {

        double a = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(idx));  //Find the area of contour

        if (a > largest_area) {

            largest_area = a;

            largest_idx = idx;
        }
    }

    if (contours.size() > 0) {

        MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(largest_idx).toArray());

        RotatedRect rbox = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new_mat);

        Point vertices[] = new Point[4];

        rbox.points(vertices);

        List<MatOfPoint> boxContours = new ArrayList<>();

        boxContours.add(new MatOfPoint(vertices));

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            Imgproc.line(origMat, vertices[i], vertices[(i + 1) % 4], new Scalar(255, 0, 0));
        }

        double rect_angle = rbox.angle - 90.0f;
        Size rect_size = rbox.size;

        double d = rect_size.width;
        rect_size.width = rect_size.height;
        rect_size.height = d;


        M = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(rbox.center, rect_angle, 1.0);


        Imgproc.warpAffine(origMat, rotated, M, origMat.size());


        if (rect_size.width > 70 && rect_size.height > 70)
            Imgproc.getRectSubPix(rotated, new Size(rect_size.width - 70, rect_size.height - 70), rbox.center, rotated);


        Imgproc.resize(rotated, rotated, origMat.size());



        Mat orr = rotated.clone();

        Imgproc.cvtColor(orr, orr, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

        Core.split(orr, channels);

        orr = channels.get(2);

        CLAHE clahe = Imgproc.createCLAHE();

        clahe.setClipLimit(1);

        clahe.apply(orr, orr);

        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(orr, orr, new Size(5, 5), 5);

        Core.meanStdDev(mGray, mu, stddev);

        Imgproc.Canny(orr, orr, (mu.get(0, 0)[0]) * 0.66, (mu.get(0, 0)[0]) * 1.33, 3, false);

        Imgproc.morphologyEx(orr, orr, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernell);

        Imgproc.dilate(orr, orr, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(3, 3)));

        Imgproc.findContours(orr, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        for (int i = contours.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i), false);  //  Find the area of contour
            if (area < min_area)
                contours.remove(i);
        }

        if (contours.size() > 0) {
            MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
            rectList.clear();
            for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
                //Convert contours(i) from MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f
                MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(idx).toArray());
                //Processing on mMOP2f1 which is in type MatOfPoint2f
                double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true) * 0.02;
                Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);

                //Convert back to MatOfPoint
                MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint(approxCurve.toArray());

                // Get bounding rect of contour
                Rect rectt = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
                rectList.add(rect);
                Mat miniature = new Mat(orr, new Rect(rectt.tl(), rectt.br()));
                mats.add(miniature);

                // draw enclosing rectangle (all same color, but you could use variable i to make them unique)
                Imgproc.rectangle(rotated, rectt.tl(), rectt.br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0));
            }
        }

        long e2 = Core.getTickCount();
        long e = e2 - e1;
        double time = e / Core.getTickFrequency();

        Log.d("timeTAG", "" + time);

        return orr;
    }
    return rotated;
```

Comment: please how did you solve your problem?